# How to plot 2 curves on a histogram in base R?

Tags: r, histogram, curve

I made this histogram with base R:
[image: Histogram]

Here is the code:

```
data=read.csv("cholesterol.csv")
newdata=subset(data, data$SEX=="female")
newdata1=subset(data, data$SEX=="male")
hist(newdata$CHOLESTEROL,breaks=10,col=rgb(red = F, green = T, blue = F,
alpha = 0.3), xlim=c(0,350), ylim=c(0,25), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", las=1, main="", xlab="Cholesterol", ylab="Frequentie", border=rgb(red = F, green = T, blue = F, alpha = 0.3))
hist(newdata1$CHOLESTEROL, breaks=10,col=rgb(red = T, green = F, blue = F, alpha = 0.4), border=rgb(red = T, green = F, blue = F, alpha = 0.4), add=T)
legend('topright', c('Female','Male'),fill = rgb(0:1,1:0,0,0.4), bty='n', border = NA)
```

I now want to plot a curve on this histogram and I want for each group (female and male) a distinct curve.
I tried several commando's (such as `lines(density(newdata$CHOLESTEROL), col="red", lty=1, lwd=1)`) but none of them resulted in a curve. I also could not find a solution on the internet, so I hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `probability=TRUE` to the calls to `hist`.  This will scale the histogram to have an area of 1, the same as the result of `density` so that they plot nicely together.  Your code above is probably adding the curve, but with the difference in scaling it looks like a horizontal line along the bottom.